# How do I pass custom parameters into the callback method of a jQuery AJAX method?

Tags: jquery, ajax, parameters, callback

I've seen various answers to this question but I'm having trouble mapping them to my situation. What I think might be the answer on some of them, seem to be old ways of coding or unfamiliar enough to me that I cannot understand how to implement them to my situation.

I've got PHP generating a records.json file which my app needs to query for the logic of several methods.

```
function queryRecords(recordId, requiredField) {
    $.ajax("javascript/records.json", {
        dataType: "json",
        success: callBack,
        error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
            alert("AJAX error: unable to retrieve records from records.json\n\n" + errorMessage);
        }
    });
}

function callBack(response) {
    $.each(response, function(index, records) {
        if (records["MediaItemID"] == recordId) {
            $.each(records, function(key, value) {
                if (key == requiredField) {
                    return value;
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

queryRecords("14", "MediaItemName");
```

Each time I need to query the records, I need to pass *recordId* and *requiredField* to get the value of that record's field (as per the loops in the callBack method). However it seems I am limited with this approach because I cannot pass these values as parameters in *success*. If I output to the console **within** *success*, I see the value, but I need access to the value outside of success and this is how far I've gotten. I've seen so many pages about this, my head hurts. Please can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the code suggested in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function just to see if I could access the value outside of the Promise, and it failed as it has always been doing...

```
var xyz = "please";

function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved');
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  const result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  xyz = result;
  //console.log(result);
  // expected output: "resolved"
}

asyncCall();

console.log(xyz);
```

It returns 'please'.

Either I'm not understanding the solutions provided, or what I'm trying to achieve is not being understood. I'm happy to accept that this is a "me" problem.

The answer would've been simple if it was just a case of setting async to false in the ajax query, but that's deprecated.

The answer is: I give up, but only because it's probably unwise for multiple methods to rely on multiple ajax calls for their logic.

So instead, I'm going to import the records from the json file into an array so I'll always have access to the data without this headache.

Answer (score -1):

Try like,

```
function queryRecords(recordId, requiredField) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      $.ajax("javascript/records.json", {
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
          resolve(callBack(recordId, requiredField, response));
        },
        error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
            reject(errorMessage);
        }
    });
  });
}

function callBack(recordId, requiredField, response) {
  $.each(response, function(index, records) {
      if (records["MediaItemID"] == recordId) {
          $.each(records, function(key, value) {
              if (key == requiredField) {
                  return value;
              }
          });
      }
  });
}
queryRecords("14", "MediaItemName").then(response => {
  // response will contain your return value
}).catch(errorMessage => {
  alert("AJAX error: unable to retrieve records from records.json\n\n" + errorMessage);
});
```

A sample implementation,

```js
function queryRecords(userId) {

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          $.ajax("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos", {
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
              resolve(callBack(userId, response));
            },
            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
                reject(errorMessage);
            }
        });
      });
    }

    function callBack(userId, response) {
      let filteredTodos = [];
      $.each(response, function(index, todo) {
          if (todo.userId == userId) {
              filteredTodos.push(todo);
          }
      });
      return filteredTodos;
    }
           
    queryRecords(1).then(filteredTodos => {
      alert(filteredTodos);
    }).catch(errorMessage => {
      alert("AJAX error: unable to retrieve records from records.json\n\n" + errorMessage);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you but it's still outputting undefined.

Comment: return value; you cannot return a value from a callback. Is that what you want to do? In that case, I can update the code with Promise. Let me know.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. Yeah I need to set up variables like **var context = queryRecords(recordId, "ConsumptionStatus");** and **var recordIsVisible = queryRecords(recordId, "RecordIsVisible") == "1" ? true : false;** so all I need is the returned value from the AJAX query.

Comment: Thank you. I'm implementing like this for testing purposes: **console.log("Outside ajax/promise: " + queryRecords("14", "MediaItemName").then(response => {}).catch(errorMessage => {
        alert("AJAX error: unable to retrieve records from records.json\n\n" + errorMessage);
    }));** but getting... **jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: Can't read property 'then' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
(http://localhost/MediaTracker/v2/javascript/frontend.js:555:51)
jquery-3.4.1.min.js Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined**

Comment: Sorry made a type. Add return before, new Promise, like, return new Promise(. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I used all your code under 'sample implementation', plus changing the version of jQuery I use. I added the following mods: **var xyz = "something, pleeeaaaseee";**   
      queryRecords(1).then(filteredTodos => {
        **xyz = filteredTodos;
        //** alert(filteredTodos);
      }).catch(errorMessage => {
        alert("AJAX error: unable to retrieve records from records.json\n\n" + errorMessage);
      });
      **console.log("Outside async: \n\n" + xyz);** and I get in the console: **Outside async: 

something, pleeeaaaseee** sigh, but thank you :)

Comment: No problem. Happy to help.. :) You are getting something please because the code is asynchronous. So the assignment you have made, xyz = filteredTodos inside the then block will be executed after you console.log('outside....). Try adding a console inside then, you will see console.log('outside..') and then array of filtered todos.

Comment: I stated *"..a records.json file which my app needs to query for the logic of several methods."* and *"..I need access to the value outside of success"* and *"..need to set up variables like var context = queryRecords(recordId, "ConsumptionStatus");"* ..I thought I established my need for access to the value retrieved from the json file *outside* of the ajax request. I have always been able to alert and console.log the value *inside* the request, but outside the request (where I need it) it's always 'undefined'. Character limit made me blunt, not complaining :) your help is much appreciated.

Comment: To confirm, l have several methods that need to do something based on the value of a field retrieved from the json file, as such, I need the retrieved value to be available outside of the ajax call to assign to a variable or for expressions in order for those methods to work. E.g. **function x() {var y = queryRecords("4","DownloadAlertID"); if (queryRecords("1","ConsumptionStatus") == "coming") {// do some funkiness}}**. But the result of the variable or expression is always undefined. So I'm a bit buggered lol

Comment: In order for you to use the value of the result of a `Promise`,  1) You can access it in `.then` 2) Using async/await Example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function